# If $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ , find all the possible values of $a$.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $f(x)=x^3+ax+2$ $\in \mathbb{Q}[x].$ If $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ , find all the possible values of $a$.

Attempt

Suppose $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$ be zero of $f(x)$ now $\alpha^3+a\alpha+2=0 $ follows $ a=\dfrac{-2-\alpha^3}{\alpha}$.

therefore for any $ a=\dfrac{-2-\alpha^3}{\alpha}$ $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}-\{0\}$ , $f(x)$is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Is my attempt correct? Can anyone verify answer?

Comment: You have a typo when you first write the equation for $a$ in terms of $\alpha$, but you fix it in the next line and it’s otherwise correct.  You might want to explain how you know the equation must have a rational root if it’s reducible, but that’s a matter of pedagogy.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you very much.